# WPF: how to remove point that my chart will be visible after many point

Tags: wpf, charts

i am populate my `chart` via `timer tick event` every one second and this is at the beginning:

http://s24.postimg.org/v7ous1plx/image.png

```
ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, int>> points

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    points.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0, r.Next(1000)));
    if (points.Count > 60)
        points.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

My `chart`:

```
<Grid>
            <chartingToolkit:Chart Name="lineChart" Margin="16,90,30,483" Background="Transparent" >
                <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Name="seriesChart" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSelectionEnabled="True" Margin="0,-37,0,37" >
                    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineSeries">
                            <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                                <Polyline x:Name="polyline"
                                          Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" 
                                          Stroke="Yellow" 
                                          StrokeThickness="2"
                                          Style="{TemplateBinding PolylineStyle}" />

                            </Canvas>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Template>
                </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
            </chartingToolkit:Chart>
        </Grid>
```

And in a few minutes i have so many point that i barely can see my `chart stroke line` so after 60 `points` that represent 1 minute i remove the first `point` so in this case my chart will be full with only 60 `points` but again i few minutes this is what i can see:

http://s7.postimg.org/eg25zhbhn/image.png

Comment: You should also post your code that binds your chart to your points collection, that's where the problem likely is.

Answer (score 0):

I have some code regarding this in one of my projects:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFToolkitProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="EmptyPointsStyle" TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint}">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="aa" TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LineSeries}">
            <Setter Property="DataPointStyle" Value="{StaticResource EmptyPointsStyle}"/>
            <Setter Property="PolylineStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Polyline}">
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeMiterLimit" Value="1"/>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LineSeries}">
                        <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                            <Polyline Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Style="{TemplateBinding PolylineStyle}" Points="{TemplateBinding Points}"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="lineChart" Title="Line Series Demo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="50" Height="254">
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries  DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding points}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

And this is the codebehind: i am starting a new thread to avoid blocking the UI and go back to it with the help of Dispatcher when doing operations on the bounded collection.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, int>> points { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        points = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
        points.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 60));
        points.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(2, 20));
        points.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(3, 50));
        points.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(4, 30));
        points.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(5, 40));
        points.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(6, 200));
        points.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(7, 1));
        points.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(8, 450));
        points.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(4, 30));
        points.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(5, 40));

        this.DataContext = this;
    }


    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        #region Adding points at runtime - test

        Task.Run(() =>
        {

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

            int pos = 300;
            var r = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    points.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, r.Next(1000)));
                    points.RemoveAt(0);
                });
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((100));
            }
        });

        #endregion Adding points at runtime - test
    }
}
```

So, here each time i'm adding a point, i am removing the first one. It works ok, but you can choose another approach by not removing the first one at each add. Depends on your needs.